# passing std::stream objects from one manager to another

Tags: c++, c++11, stream

I am working on implementing a ResourceManager for my game and I have come across a slight problem regarding Streams.

In my Resource Manager, there is a Locator object that searches for a file. When the locator finds the file, it returns a ResourceStream object (`virtual ResourceStream * FileLocator::locateFile(const String &name);`). Then, Loader object parses the file and creates a Resource object (e.g `virtual Resource * ResourceLoader::parseStream(ResourceStream * stream);`).

The problem is, I don't know how to implement the ResourceStream as I don't really know how std::streams are used. As a good practice, how are streams passed between objects? Should it be passed via pointers or move semantics considering that, streams will be deleted at the end of the scope? In the problem above, how should I make the streams move? Should I make the ResourceStream inherited from `std::fstream` and pass it by `std::move`? Or should I use the ResourceStream a wrapper around an `std::streambuf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementing a [stream buffer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/) (that can be passed around as a parameter). When you need I/O on the buffer, create an std::istream or std::ostream on it.

This approach will allow you to have access to properly formatted I/O using `std::[i/o]stream` with no effort on your part (i.e. you just have to define what adding or getting bytes from the stream means, not formatting.

Code should look like this:

```
class ResourceStream: public std::streambuf {
    ... // you implement this
};

virtual Resource parseStream(std::streambuf * streambuf)
{
    std::istream    in(streambuf);
    Resource        r;
    in >> r; // assumes an std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&in, Resource& r)
             // is defined
    if(in >> r)
        return r;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error{"bad stream for parsing resource"};
}
```

Edit:

On a second look, this seems to be the x-y problem. The correct solution is to define i/o operators for your Resource class:

What you need to write:

```
class Resource {
// ...
};

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Resource& r) {
    return in after reading from it
}
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Resource& r) {
    return in after writing into it
}
```

In your model the  ResourceStream object will be a std::ifstream opened on the located file and your ResourceManager will look like this:

```
// boost::path can be replaced by std::string containing the file path
virtual boost::path FileLocator::locateFile(const String &name);

// locate file and get resource:
auto path = locator.locateFile("serializedresource.data");
std::ifstream input(path);
Resource r;
if(input >> r)
    // r was read correctly
else
    // stream does not contain a serialized r / throw an exception
```

Comment: I really like the idea of implementing my own stream buffer but if I am going to use std::[i/o]fstream wouldn't it make more sense to use `basic_filebuf`? Also, does streambuf change when the file is loaded as binary or text or its the fstream's job to "parse" it as text or binary? I am still researching and reading about streambuf, as I never had any experience even using one.

Comment: A streambuf is binary. Translating from bytes to formatted data is the responsibility of the stream (on top of the buffer).

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to pass by reference, but from what you describe, the stream will be created in and returned from a separate function, and should live beyond the lifetime of the creating function.  Traditionally, you'd return a pointer to a dynamically allocated stream, which the callee would have to delete.  (This is what `std::auto_ptr` was designed for.)  In C++11, this solution still works (but you might want to use `std::unique_ptr` instead).  Alternatively, you might be able to use move semantics for the return, although they won't respect the polymorphic type.  In other words: if `locateFile` creates a `std::ifstream`, the local variable you initialize with its return value will have to be an `std::ifstream`, and not simply an `std::istream`.  This probably exposes too much of the internals of `locateFile`, and makes the `std::auto_ptr`/`std::unique_ptr` solution preferable.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways of passing streams (I think):

- As an argument (non const reference to a function)
- As an return value encapsulated in a smart pointer 
  (std/boost::shared_ptr or unique_ptr)
- Move semantics (which the compiler may not support)